# ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I wrote a SQL Query but I am getting this Error:

```
Msg 145, Level 15, State 1, Procedure GetClientSpecificCollection, Line 18
ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.
```

**My Query Is Here:**

```
    SELECT DISTINCT CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), CBPD.AddedDate, 106) AS [Date],
                CBD.BillNo                                AS [BillNo],
                CBPD.IsOpening                            AS [Opening],
                CASE
                  WHEN CBPD.PaymentMode = 1 THEN 'Cash Payment'
                  WHEN CBPD.PaymentMode = 2 THEN 'By Cheque, '
                                                 + Cast(CBPD.CheckNo AS VARCHAR(10)) + ', '
                                                 + CBPD.BankName
                  WHEN CBPD.PaymentMode = 3 THEN 'NEFT Payment'
                  WHEN CBPD.PaymentMode = 4 THEN 'Bank Draft'
                  WHEN CBPD.PaymentMode = 5 THEN 'Online Payment'
                  ELSE 'NA'
                END                                       AS [PaymentMode],
                CBPD.PayableAmount                        AS [BillingAmount],
                CBPD.PaymentAmount                        AS [PaymentAmount],
                CBPD.RemainAmount                         AS [BillAmount],
                CBD.RemainAmount                          AS [RemainForNext]
FROM   ClientBillingDetail CBD
       INNER JOIN ClientBillPaymentDetail CBPD
               ON CBD.ClientId = CBPD.ClientId
WHERE  CBD.ClientId = @ClientId
       AND CBD.CompanyNameId = 1
       AND ( IsOpening = 1
              OR IsRemaining = 1 )
ORDER  BY IsOpening DESC,
          CBPD.BillNo,
          CBPD.AddedDate
```

This i s my whole query anyone can tell what is problem in this query and how may i correct to this query.

Comment: `ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.`

Comment: Hello @Felix I don't understand what is meaning of this error line can u make my query correct.

Comment: The error message is pretty straightforward.

Comment: The error message means that `IsOpening, CBPD,BillNo.CBPD.AddedDate` must appear in the `SELECT` list

Comment: If i know this error then i also made it correct.

Comment: `IsOpening, CBPD,BillNo,CBPD.AddedDate ' are appearing in select statement

Comment: `CBD.BillNo` is appearing in the `SELECT` list, but `CBPD.BillNo` is there in the `ORDER BY`.

Comment: **ORDER BY items** - that means all the columns appearing in your `ORDER BY` **must appear in the select list** that means all the columns in your order by section must appear in your select section.

Comment: It is still giving me same error . after trying ur all solutions

Comment: Post your revised query

Comment: You cannot select `CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), CBPD.AddedDate, 106)` and then order by `AddedDate`, you must sort by the exact same column specifications, so either select `AddedDate` or order by `CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), CBPD.AddedDate, 106)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the alias name instead of using CBPD.IsOpening;

Like this

```
ORDER BY        Opening DESC, CBPD.BillNo, CBPD.AddedDate
```

I thinks that solves the issue

Comment: thnx to all for helping

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you are converting `CBPD.AddedDate` in your `SELECT` statement. Try this query

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    CONVERT(varchar(11), CBPD.AddedDate, 106) AS [Date],
    CBPD.BillNo AS [BillNo],
    CBPD.IsOpening AS [Opening],
    CASE
        WHEN CBPD.PaymentMode = 1 THEN 'Cash Payment'
        WHEN CBPD.PaymentMode = 2 THEN 'By Cheque, ' + CAST(CBPD.CheckNo AS varchar(10)) + ', ' + CBPD.BankName
        WHEN CBPD.PaymentMode = 3 THEN 'NEFT Payment'
        WHEN CBPD.PaymentMode = 4 THEN 'Bank Draft'
        WHEN CBPD.PaymentMode = 5 THEN 'Online Payment'
        ELSE 'NA'
    END AS [PaymentMode],
    CBPD.PayableAmount AS [BillingAmount],
    CBPD.PaymentAmount AS [PaymentAmount],
    CBPD.RemainAmount AS [BillAmount],
    CBD.RemainAmount AS [RemainForNext]
FROM ClientBillingDetail CBD
INNER JOIN ClientBillPaymentDetail CBPD
    ON CBD.ClientId = CBPD.ClientId
WHERE CBPD.ClientId = @ClientId
AND CBD.CompanyNameId = 1
AND (CBPD.IsOpening = 1
OR CBPD.IsRemaining = 1)
ORDER BY CBPD.IsOpening DESC,
CBPD.BillNo, 
CONVERT(varchar(11),CBPD.AddedDate, 106)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't test this now, but if you really need to convert the date, you might have to do this:

```
SELECT 
  CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), CBPD.AddedDate, 106) AS [Date],
  [BillNo],
  [Opening],
  [PaymentMode],
  [BillingAmount],
  [PaymentAmount],
  [BillAmount],
  [RemainForNext]
from (
    SELECT DISTINCT CBPD.AddedDate AS [Date],
                CBD.BillNo                                AS [BillNo],
                CBPD.IsOpening                            AS [Opening],
                CASE
                  WHEN CBPD.PaymentMode = 1 THEN 'Cash Payment'
                  WHEN CBPD.PaymentMode = 2 THEN 'By Cheque, '
                                                 + Cast(CBPD.CheckNo AS VARCHAR(10)) + ', '
                                                 + CBPD.BankName
                  WHEN CBPD.PaymentMode = 3 THEN 'NEFT Payment'
                  WHEN CBPD.PaymentMode = 4 THEN 'Bank Draft'
                  WHEN CBPD.PaymentMode = 5 THEN 'Online Payment'
                  ELSE 'NA'
                END                                       AS [PaymentMode],
                CBPD.PayableAmount                        AS [BillingAmount],
                CBPD.PaymentAmount                        AS [PaymentAmount],
                CBPD.RemainAmount                         AS [BillAmount],
                CBD.RemainAmount                          AS [RemainForNext]
FROM   ClientBillingDetail CBD
       INNER JOIN ClientBillPaymentDetail CBPD
               ON CBD.ClientId = CBPD.ClientId
WHERE  CBD.ClientId = @ClientId
       AND CBD.CompanyNameId = 1
       AND ( IsOpening = 1
              OR IsRemaining = 1 )
) X
ORDER  BY X.Opening,
          X.BillNo,
          X.[Date]
```

This way you don't have distinct and order by in the same select.

If AddedDate is datetime, you should convert it to date first, so that the distinct works as it should.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use aliases in your select clause in order by clause as below

```
SELECT DISTINCT CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), CBPD.AddedDate, 106) AS [Date],
            CBD.BillNo                                AS [BillNo],
            CBPD.IsOpening                            AS [Opening],
            CASE
              WHEN CBPD.PaymentMode = 1 THEN 'Cash Payment'
              WHEN CBPD.PaymentMode = 2 THEN 'By Cheque, '
                                             + Cast(CBPD.CheckNo AS VARCHAR(10)) + ', '
                                             + CBPD.BankName
              WHEN CBPD.PaymentMode = 3 THEN 'NEFT Payment'
              WHEN CBPD.PaymentMode = 4 THEN 'Bank Draft'
              WHEN CBPD.PaymentMode = 5 THEN 'Online Payment'
              ELSE 'NA'
            END                                       AS [PaymentMode],
            CBPD.PayableAmount                        AS [BillingAmount],
            CBPD.PaymentAmount                        AS [PaymentAmount],
            CBPD.RemainAmount                         AS [BillAmount],
            CBD.RemainAmount                          AS [RemainForNext]
FROM   ClientBillingDetail CBD
   INNER JOIN ClientBillPaymentDetail CBPD
           ON CBD.ClientId = CBPD.ClientId
WHERE  CBD.ClientId = @ClientId
   AND CBD.CompanyNameId = 1
   AND ( IsOpening = 1
          OR IsRemaining = 1 )
ORDER  BY [Opening] DESC,
      [BillNo],
      [Date]
```